# How do I access every index of a specific Array inside an AJAX object

Tags: ajax

I'm calling an `ajax` for `giphy`, with this code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: queryURL,
  method: "GET"
}). then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
```

when I look at the console log there's an object with the first property being data.  Each index of data is another object, inside this object are two properties i'm trying to pull, `rating` and `url`. I want to be able to list the `rating` and `url` not just of a specific index, but every index in that data array.  What would be the best way to do that?  Currently I've tried a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i<response.data.length;i++){
  var dataIndex = response.data[i];
}  
then <creating a variable something like> 
  var imgURL = response.data[dataIndex].url
```

but its not working.

Here's the entire code

```
function displayTopicGif() {
var topic = $(this).attr("data-name");
// query url
var queryURL = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=" + topic + "&limit=20&rating=r&api_key=";

$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    // for loop to create a variable for the index of the objects data
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        var dataIndex = response.data[i];

    }
    // where the gif's will be dumped
    var topicDiv = $("<div class='topic'>");
    // rating of gif
    var rating = response.data[0].rating;
    console.log(rating);
    // Creating an element to have the rating displayed
    var pOne = $("<p>").text("Rating: " + rating);
    // add to the rating element
    topicDiv.append(pOne);
    // retrieve the IMG of the gif

    var imgURL = response.data[0].url;

    var image = $("<img>").attr("src", imgURL);
    topicDiv.append(image);
    // put gif into topic-view div
    $("#topic-view").prepend(topicDiv);


});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that something is an object using [$.isPlainObject](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.isplainobject/) and then read through its properties via:

```
for (key in object) {
   var value = object[key];
   //log
}
```

Or you can get the keys using [Object.getOwnPropertyNames();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames).  See this sample excerpt from MDN:

```
const object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c"]
```